# Named list members with the same name

Tags: r

When I want to "merge" two lists I usually use the `c`-function:

```
merge <- c(list(a=1), list(a=2))
```

Now I have made a list with two equally named members.

```
merge
$a
[1] 1

$a
[1] 2
```

`merge` is a list of 2, but I can not access the second member by its name (only number).

Can anyone explain the internals of R that make this behavior possible? I was expecting behavior similar to a dictionary, but it seems this is not enforced. Not even an error...

I also wonder whether I am "merging" in the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to have different names to access the elements.  For this, we can utilize the `make.unique`

```
names(merge) <- make.unique(names(merge), sep="")
merge$a
#[1] 1
merge$a1 
#[1] 2
```